# A diffeomorphism is a coordinate chart

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

The following is Proposition 6.11 in Tu's book on manifolds:

Let $U$ be an open subset of a manifold $M$ of dimension $n$. If $F: U \rightarrow F(U) \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is a diffeomorphism onto an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, then $(U, F)$ is a chart in the differentiable structure of $M$.

His proof:
For any chart $(U_\alpha, \phi_\alpha)$ in the maximal atlas of $M$, both $\phi_\alpha$ and $\phi_\alpha^{-1}$ are $C^\infty$. As composites of $C^\infty$ maps, both $F \circ \phi_\alpha^{-1}$ and $\phi_\alpha \circ F^{-1}$ are $C^\infty$. Hence $(U, F)$ is compatible with the maximal atlas. By the maximality of the atlas, the chart $(U, F)$ is in the atlas.

The proof considers a coordinate domain of $U_\alpha$, so that the range of $\phi_\alpha^{-1}$ is $U_\alpha$. However $F$ is defined on $U$ not $U_\alpha$, so how are we able to deduce that $F \circ \phi_\alpha^{-1}$ (and similarly $\phi_\alpha \circ F^{-1}$) is well defined? Are we implicitly taking the domain to always be $U \cap U_\alpha$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

$ \phi_\alpha \circ F^{-1}:F(U)\cap \phi_\alpha (U_\alpha)\to\Bbb R^n$.  That's on *overlaps*.  Similarly $
 F\circ\phi_\alpha^{-1}:\phi_\alpha(U_\alpha) \cap F(U)\to \Bbb R^n$.

Since this is true for *any* chart $(\phi_\alpha, U_\alpha) $, by maximality $(F,U)$ is in the atlas.  That's it's a chart.

Comment: For the domain of $\phi_\alpha \circ F^{-1}$, did you mean $F(U) \cap \phi_\alpha( U_\alpha)$? Because $F(U) \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ whereas $U_\alpha \subset M$. Likewise I believe the domain of $F \circ \phi^{-1}_\alpha$ should be $\phi_\alpha(U_\alpha) \cap F(U)$, right?

Comment: Yeah,  you're right.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

Certainly $(U,F)$ is a chart of the *topological manifold $M$*. In section 5.2 (Compatible Charts) Tu introduces the concept of *transition functions* between two charts $(U,\phi)$ and $(V,\psi)$ of a topological manifold $M$. These are the two maps
$$\phi \circ \psi^{-1} :\psi(U ∩V) \stackrel{\psi^{-1}}{\to} U \cap V \stackrel{\phi}{\to} \phi(U ∩V), \\ \psi \circ \phi^{-1} :\phi(U ∩V) \stackrel{\phi^{-1}}{\to} U \cap V \stackrel{\psi}{\to} \psi(U ∩V) .$$